# .htaccess rewrite base folder but not content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using a framework which rewrites all URLs to index.php unless the file or folder actually exists.

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

However, I have a directory called 'media', and a page with a URL of '/media'. I need to make it so going to '/media' gets routed through to index.php, but viewing something *inside* the 'media' directory gets displayed as usual.

So:

```
http://example.com/some-page - routed through index.php (already does this)
http://example.com/media - routed through index.php as well
http://example.com/media/images/hello.jpg - asset served as usual
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^media$ index.php/media [PT,L]
```

This lists the contents of the 'media' folder as usual.

```
RewriteRule ^media/$ index.php/media
```

This causes a redirect loop.

I am unsure what other syntax would work.

Answer (score 1):

If /media/images/hello.jpg is an actual file then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is already ignoring this.

If it is not then you place this rule **before your existing routing rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^media/.+$ - [NC,L]
```